# Duda con operador new en c++

Tags: c++

Pasa que estoy aprendiendo sobre asignación dinámica de arreglos. Entiendo que new reserva la cantidad de memoria necesaria en tiempo de ejecución y no de compilación.

A continuación, ilustro un poco esto:

```
int* ptr = new int[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

En ese momento pensé...

¿Por qué usar new?, si puedo pedir la cantidad de notas que va a ingresar al usuario, y guardar esto en una variable para luego poner esta como tamaño del vector.

Así no estaría creando un vector a la ligera, sino que primero le pregunto al usuario cuanto espacio usara, tal cual como se hace con new.

Por ejemplo:

```
int tam;
cout<<"\nIngresa el tamaño del vector: "<<endl;
cin>>tam;
int numeros[tam];

// Luego a través de un for le pediría los datos al usuario para rellenar el vector.
```

¿Por qué entonces es tan importante el operador new para la creación de vectores dinámicos?

No me queda del todo claro el uso del operador new.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debes usar `int numeros[tam]` por que el compilador no conoce el valor de `tam` sin ejecutar el programa, ya que el usuario lo ingresa.

Si quieres preguntar al usuario la cantidad de elementos e inicializar un array con tal cantidad solo debes:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int tam;
    std::cout << "\nIngresa el tamaño del vector: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> tam;
    
    int* lista = new int[tam];
}
```

El operador `new` reservará memoria para el listado y te devolverá el puntero al primer elemento. Adicionalmente si es un objeto, inicializará el objeto según los constructores.

La razón por la cual no debes usar `int numeros[tam]` está definido en el estándar C++11 (punto 8.3.4, pag 179):

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present,
> it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero. The constant expression
> specifies the bound of (number of elements in) the array. If the value of the constant expression is N, the array
> has N elements numbered 0 to N-1, and the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list array of N
> T”

Sacado del documento [C++ International Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), También hay un [enlace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/) interesante que lo explica en inglés.

Comment: Dices que el compilador no conoce el valor de tam, pero aun así el programa funciona. Entonces, ¿a que te refieres exactamente con?

"No debes usar int números[tam] por que el compilador no conoce el valor de tam sin ejecutar el programa, ya que el usuario lo ingresa".

Comment: Depende del compilador y la versión de C++ que uses. Como ya habrás visto, C++ es bastante extenso y algunas versiones de compiladores que son permisibles con código C (ej: C99), no son estándar o son superiores (ej: C++14, [C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), C++20, etc) podrían implementarlo como parte de la sintaxis y funciona totalmente. Por ahora y por motivos educacionales, es mejor mantener la práctica estándar de usar `new` ya que todos la conocen bien. Este es el motivo por el cual usé el termino "debes" en vez de "puedes"

Answer (score 1):

En C se solía usar alloc y malloc lo cual devuelve un apuntador a void (void*), sin embargo el oprador new establece un espacio(relacionado con una dirección de memoria) para una instancia de una clase definida y no necesariamente un void*.

Answer (score 1):

Conviene mas cuando se trabaja con puntero de punteros y más aún si se trabaja con Objetos.
Porque tendrás que llamar al tamaño de los arreglos previamente.

Un ejemplo que es para ingresar datos en una matriz.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int **alum, nAlum, nNotas;
    int i,j;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de alumnos: "; cin>>nAlum;
    alum=new int*[nAlum];
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de notas: "; cin>>nNotas;
    for(i=0; i<nAlum; i++){
        alum[i]=new int[nNotas];
    }
    for(i=0;i<nAlum;i++){
        cout<<"Alumno "<<i<<": ";
        for(j=0;j<nNotas;j++){
            cin>>*(*(alum+i)+j);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<nAlum;i++){
        cout<<"Alumno "<<i<<": ";
        for(j=0;j<nNotas;j++){
            cout<<*(*(alum+i)+j);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```